# Ionic 3: Local notifications "click" event APP CLOSED not work

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m using local notifications native plugin on my ionic 3 project (latest version), but when I click on notification and my app is closed the click event is not triggered.
It works when app is in background or foreground.

I use local notifications inside a provider and my on click code is inside its constructor but when app is closed it's not working.
I’ve tried to write code inside platform ready in app/app.component.ts but this approach does not work.
This is my code:

app/app.component.ts

```
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  rootPage: any;

constructor(
public platform: Platform,
public menu: MenuController,
public statusBar: StatusBar,
public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
public BeaconServiceProvider: BeaconServiceProvider, /* my provider with local notifications*/
public RemoteServiceProvider: RemoteServiceProvider,
public translate: TranslateService,
public globalization: Globalization,
private oneSignal: OneSignal,
public ga: GoogleAnalytics
  ) {
......
}
}
```

My provider

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { IBeacon } from '@ionic-native/ibeacon';
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';
import { RemoteServiceProvider } from '../remote-service/remote-service';
import { StorageProvider } from '../storage/storage';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NavController, App} from "ionic-angular/index";
import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/google-analytics';

@Injectable()
export class BeaconServiceProvider {

  remoteBeacons: Array<{major: string, minor: string}> = [];
  localBeacons: Array<{major: string, minor: string, date: any}> = [];
  bluetoothInit: boolean = false;
  private navCtrl: NavController;

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public storage: Storage,
    public ibeacon: IBeacon,
    public translate: TranslateService,
    public localNotifications: LocalNotifications,
    public RemoteServiceProvider: RemoteServiceProvider,
    public StorageProvider: StorageProvider,
    public ga: GoogleAnalytics,
    private app: App
  ) {
    console.log('Hello BeaconProvider Provider');

    this.localBeacons = this.StorageProvider.localBeacons;

    this.navCtrl = this.app.getActiveNav();

    let thiz_app = this.app;
    let remote = this.RemoteServiceProvider;
    this.localNotifications.on("click", function(notification, state){

      this.ga.trackEvent(
        "Notifiche Beacon (" + remote.version_code + ")",
        "Apertura notifica",
        "Click sulla notifica beacon " + " {" + notification.message + "}",
    1
     );

     let nav = thiz_app.getActiveNav();

     let data = JSON.parse(notification.data);
     let page_id = data.page_id;
     page_id = page_id.toString();

    switch(page_id)
    {
       case "" :
       case "0" :
          break;
    case "-1" : //Contact Page
        if (nav == null)
          nav.push('ContactPage');
        else if (nav.getActive().component.name != 'ContactPage')
          nav.push('ContactPage');
      break;
    default :

      remote.isPageListNew(page_id).subscribe(result => {
          let page = result.has_subpages ? 'List2Page' : 'ItemDetailsPage';

          if (nav == null)
            nav.push(page, { item: result });
          else
          {
            if( nav.getActive().component.name != page)
              nav.push(page, { item: result });
            else
            {
              let item_id = nav.getActive().data.item.id;
              if (item_id != result.id)
                nav.push(page, { item: result });
            }
          }
      });

  }

});

  }
```

Any ideas why my code does not work?
Thanks

Comment: My one was using Ionic 3.9.9 and it works well on iOS (not working on Android). Have you solved your problem?